# Are these two Activerecord queryes just one Database query. Trying to solve an N+1

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am curious if these two queries are the same for the purposes of solving an N+1 query. I only want one query to the database being made. If they are the same, why? How does Activerecord handle this? What is going on?

```
products = Product.where(user_id: user.id)
products.includes(:restrictions).select do |product|
   !product.restrictions.map(&:state_name).include?("CT")
end
```

and

```
Product.includes(:restrictions).where(user_id: user.id).select do |product|
   product.restrictions.map(&:state_name).include?("CT")
end
```

A `Product` has many `Restrictions`

Comment: Both are same queries, only the `where` is chained directly to `includes` in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

Those 2 are exactly same..you can check out their sql versions to verify

```
Product.includes(:restrictions).where(user_id: user.id).to_sql
```

But the fact that the first one is written on different lines will query the db twice..
First only

```
Product.where(user_id: user.id)
```

Second with `includes` which preloads the associated records

```
Product.includes(:restrictions).where(user_id: user.id)
```

This pretty much explains the concept of [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) which are chainable to active record collection objects. You can divide a query into parts and define them as `scope`s as well..

Comment: Clear cut answer!